# How to set publish date for slideshow

Tags: slideshow

How can i set time for publish and date for deliting each pic?
I Upload the picture to a folder and the use a carousel to show them.

Code below:

```
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if (!empty($row["file_location"])) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            // remove the slide1920 part
                            echo substr($row["file_location"],8);
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="<?php echo $row["file_location"]; ?>" class="img-thumbnail"
                                 alt="<?php echo $row["file_location"]; ?>" width="250" height="190">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href='deleteslide.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'>Delete</a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                <?php }
            }
        }
        ?>

    </table>
```